# Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'bundle id for app extension' signing problem

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, code-signing

When I am trying to automatically manage signing for an archive with XCode 12.1. I receive an error message related to my app extension. There were no problems previously (with earlier XCode versions) and I didn't change anything. Error is the following:

```
Failed to register bundle identifier The app identifier 'bundle id for app extension' cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

No profiles for 'bundle id for app extension' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'bundle id for app extension'.
```

Bundle id for extension is correct and starts with the bundle id of the app. Something like:

```
id.bundle.app
id.bundle.app.extension
```

This is weird as profile is there and is the same as was previously.

[image].

As I am signing an extension, I am using a wildcard. Profiles are up to date. I also tried to recreate all profiles from scratch, it didn't help.
At the same time automatically manage signing is enabled in XCode and there is no error.

What can be the problem?

UPD.
If I sign manually and while signing select wildcard it works, but it is weird that it doesn't work for automatic signing.

Comment: Try switching off the automatic signing and then switch it on again (sounds like IT Crowd). Do this for the problematic target or if that does not help also for the main project and then the extensions.

Comment: I've tried it multiple times, it doesn't help :(

Comment: Ok - sorry about that. Maybe log into your account and check that all is up to date and create specific cert. Can you even use a wildcard nowadays? I suspect that combined with auto is the problem. (I did see your update). Also (of course) check in preferences > accounts that your session hasn't expired and that all is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
The problem was that I didn't create an identifier for my sticker extension and when I was working with signing I used a wildcard. It was working perfectly until I changed XCode to a newer version.

So, to fix the problem, I created an identifier for stickers extension, using the correct naming

```
id.bundle.app
id.bundle.app.extension
```